# How to stable_sort without copying?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, c++03, stable-sort

Why does `stable_sort` need a copy constructor? (`swap` should suffice, right?)
Or rather, how do I `stable_sort` a range without copying any elements?

```
#include <algorithm>

class Person
{
    Person(Person const &);  // Disable copying
public:
    Person() : age(0) { }
    int age;
    void swap(Person &other) { using std::swap; swap(this->age, other.age); }
    friend void swap(Person &a, Person &b) { a.swap(b); }
    bool operator <(Person const &other) const { return this->age < other.age; }
};

int main()
{
    static size_t const n = 10;
    Person people[n];
    std::stable_sort(people, people + n);
}
```

Comment: Frankly, off the top of my head I'm not aware of any stable-sort algorithm that would be inherently based on *swap* operation. All of them seem to be based on *copy* or, more precisely, *move* operation. Granted, you can emulate *move* through *swap*, but it is would be strange to expect the standard library do that inside its implementation.

Comment: @AndreyT: Actually, that pops up another question for me... I was going to ask you "why didn't they just sort iterators based on their targets instead of the elements themselves?" but now I have no idea how to (efficiently) use iterators for ranking... hence a new question! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791810/how-to-reorder-items-which-are-only-swap-able

Comment: @AndreyT: Hmm, maybe I asked that question too soon. You could just use `sort` for the reordering, then swap the ranks *as well as* the items, right? That way you'll maintain the correspondences between the items and the rankings, and you'll never have to copy items... it should work fine? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Creating an additional "index" array (with pointers or iterators) and `std::sort`-ing that array instead is always a simple and viable approach to perform stable sort (of the "index" array). In addition to your comparison criteria (like comparing `age` above) you also have to compare the iterator values, which will "stabilize" the sort. However, in order to rearrange the *original* array in accordance with your sorted index (if you really need that) you will still need a *move* operation.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yeah, I'm looking for sorting the *original* array -- I was just trying to see if that could be achieved through using an additional temporary array. So you're saying swap isn't enough -- I'd really need move? (Why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon the discussion in the OP, and because I found it interesting, here's a solution which uses only swap to sort the original vector (by using a pointer wrapper to sort indices).

Edit: this is the solution v2, which swaps in-place.

Edit (by OP): An STL-friendly version which doesn't require C++11.

```
template<class Pred>
struct swapping_stable_sort_pred
{
    Pred pred;
    swapping_stable_sort_pred(Pred const &pred) : pred(pred) { }

    template<class It>
    bool operator()(
        std::pair<It, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type> const &a,
        std::pair<It, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type> const &b) const
    {
        bool less = this->pred(*a.first, *b.first);
        if (!less)
        {
            bool const greater = this->pred(*b.first, *a.first);
            if (!greater) { less = a.second < b.second; }
        }
        return less;
    }
};

template<class It, class Pred>
void swapping_stable_sort(It const begin, It const end, Pred const pred)
{
    typedef std::pair<It, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type> Pair;
    std::vector<Pair> vp;
    vp.reserve(static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(begin, end)));
    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    { vp.push_back(std::make_pair(it, std::distance(begin, it))); }
    std::sort(vp.begin(), vp.end(), swapping_stable_sort_pred<Pred>(pred));
    std::vector<Pair *> vip(vp.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vp.size(); i++)
    { vip[static_cast<size_t>(vp[i].second)] = &vp[i]; }

    for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < vp.size(); i++)
    {
        typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type &j = vp[i].second;
        using std::swap;
        swap(*(begin + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(i)), *(begin + j));
        swap(j, vip[i]->second);
        swap(vip[j], vip[vip[j]->second]);
    }
}

template<class It>
void swapping_stable_sort(It const begin, It const end)
{ return swapping_stable_sort(begin, end, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>()); }
```

Comment: Haha, default-constructing and swapping is cheating... It's avoiding the crux of the question, whose difficulty is in how to avoid making new objects! =P But nice try. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad Well the thing is, you cannot avoid to create new objects if you want to use standard library sorts (at the very least, you will need a container of indices). If you are willing to roll out your own sort algorithm, you have 2 options: something slow and easy to implement like a bubble sort (I could write that in 2 lines of code), or something efficient but more complicated.

Comment: Sorry, by "new objects" I meant objects of the type in the array -- obviously indices are OK. I just meant that it should work if the type only has a swap, and no accessible constructors.

Comment: @Mehrdad Figured out a way to swap in place, it just required a bit more bookkeeping (see improved code). I'm not sure if it's worth it. I'm also not sure if the aggravation I've incurred was worth it, either :)

Comment: Oooh interesting... I started going a similar route (with `pair<size_t, Iterator>`) but I didn't get it to work :) I'll try that out, thanks!

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! :D Thanks! (I also edited your answer to add a slightly more STL-friendly version, which also avoids `stable_sort` altogether, just to illustrate that as well.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't own a copy of the standard. For what it's worth, this is the wording from a freely available 2010 draft:

25.4.1.2 stable_sort

[...]

Requires: The type of *first shall satisfy the Swappable requirements (Table 37), the MoveConstructible
requirements (Table 33), and the the MoveAssignable requirements (Table 35).

Testing with the latest Visual C++, it does allow sorting when a move constructor is defined but the copy constructor is private.

So to answer your question: you're out of luck. Use something other than std::stable_sort or use a wrapper class.

Comment: The C++ Standards Committee regularly releases updates on its "C++ Working Draft" at http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/. Most current one is from 2012-11-02 at www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf