# std::sort without copy construction

Tags: c++, sorting, standard-library

Assume that I have a vector of objects where:

- copy construction and assignments are expensive
- default construction and swapping of two objects is cheap.

This seems quite standard for objects with references to big data -- for example a vector of vectors.

**Question**: Is there a way to sort this vector using `std::sort`, or some other sorting routine from the standard library, so that no copying takes place, but swap is used instead? I'm looking for a pre-`c++0x` solution (**no move semantics**).

Overloading the `std::swap` seemed like a first natural attempt, and it does help a bit, but it gets rid of only a small fraction of the copying.

**Note**: Example of gcc behaviour

To sort `100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81`, my gcc std::sort calls into 19 copy constructors, 92 assignments, and 6 swaps.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791458/how-to-stable-sort-without-copying/

The solution is much simpler if you are allowed to default-construct.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but is it mandatory the original *vector* be sorted? I mean, can you, for example, build a reference vector and sort *that* based on your original sorting criteria, using it for whatever nefarious purpose you have for sorted results, while keeping the original vector in a const-state? Probably not, but worth at least a ponder if you haven't considered it.

Comment: @AndreiTita You're right, and that does in a roundabout way answer the question. But, since with move semantics this can be done with a few lines of code, I was hoping it could also be done directly using some weird template trickery.

Answer (score 2):

```
// C++03 solution won't work with arrays and some other custom containers.
// Mostly drop this block:
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
namespace aux {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<typename C> auto adl_begin( C&& c )->decltype( begin(c) );
  template<typename C> auto adl_end( C&& c )->decltype( end(c) );

  template<typename C>
  struct container_traits:
    std::iterator_traits< typename std::decay< decltype( aux::adl_begin( *(C*)nullptr ) ) >::type >
  {
    typedef typename std::decay< decltype( adl_begin( *(C*)nullptr ) ) >::type iterator_type;
  };
}

// C++03 solution won't work with arrays.  Inside std::less, use Container::value_type:
template<
  typename Container,
  typename Comparison = std::less<
    typename aux::container_traits<Container>::value_type
  >
>
void indirect_sort_then_swap( Container& c, Comparison&& comp = Comparison() ) {
  typedef aux::container_traits<Container> con_traits;
  typedef typename con_traits::value_type value_type;
  typedef typename con_traits::iterator_type iterator_type;
  std::vector< iterator_type > indirect;
  {
    // C++03 solution can use c.begin(), but will not work with arrays:
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    auto begin_ = begin(c);
    auto end_ = end(c);
    for( auto it = begin_; it != end_; ++it ) {
      indirect.push_back( it );
    }
  }
  // In C++03, write a functor class that does this:
  auto indirect_sort = [&comp]( iterator_type const& left, iterator_type const& right )->bool {
    return comp(*left, *right);
  };
  std::sort( indirect.begin(), indirect.end(), indirect_sort );
  // at this point, indirect is a vector with the contents of c sorted by iterator:
  // a hard part remains, namely to take this information and sort c with minimal swaps
  // That is hard.  I will instead create an easy approach, namely create an empty
  // copy of c full of empty elements, and directly swap the correct entry of c into
  // each slot, then I swap c with its copy.
  // the downside is that my container now needs to support push_back.  Oh well.
  Container c2;
  // C++03 solution cannot use auto here.  But we know the type of indirect:
  for (auto it = indirect.begin(); it != indirect.end(); ++it) {
    // See previous comment
    auto itv = *it;
    c2.push_back( value_type() );
    using std::swap;
    swap( *itv, c2.back() );
  }
  // by this point, the contents of c have been swap-moved to c2
  // swap them back:
  {
    using std::swap;
    swap( c, c2 );
  }
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int> foo;
   foo.push_back(7);
   foo.push_back(3);
   indirect_sort_then_swap(foo);
   for (auto i:foo) {
      std::cout << i << "\n";
   }
}
```

something like the above is a viable approach.  I wrote a bunch of it in C++11, but included comments on how to strip out the extra C++11 stuff (it actually simplifies the code in some cases, but removes the ability to handle some container-like things).

The basic idea is to sort a `vector` of `iterator`s into your original container.  Then we create a temporary container, stuff trivial `value_type`s into it, `swap` those trivial `value_type`s with the correct data from the original container (as determined by the `vector` of sorted `iterator`s), then `swap` this temporary container for our original container.

There is lots of allocation, but hopefully of cheap stuff.

For this to work, the data you are sorting needs be trivial constructable.  For this to be efficient, the data you are working with when trivially constructed needs to be cheap, and `swap` needs to be efficient.

I attempted to make this as ADL friendly as I can, because I find that to be good practice.

Answer (score 1):

[Heap-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_sort) is a swap-only sort which is not stable (the order of equivalent elements may change during the sorting). I answered an [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212701/stdsort-does-not-always-call-stdswap/14213028#14213028) where I implemented the heap-sort myself ([PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/5SVm6Tz9)), but you may find better and more flexible implementations out there.

The conclusion was that g++'s `std::sort` used 35 copy, 19 assignment, 10 swap and 35 delete (99 operations altogether) for 20 elements, my heap sort used 62 swaps and nothing else.

I just bumped into a stable sort which uses only swap [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791458/how-to-stable-sort-without-copying/). I did not look into it deeper.