# How to force std::sort to use move constructor and move-assignment?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, move-semantics

I have a class `Data` which is (as for now) non-copyable. `std::sort` on `std::vector<Data>` works because I have defined move-constructor and move-assignment for `Data`. I do it this way because the class has a lot of data inside and copying the contents would be too slow. However, I am considering now adding a copy constructor `Data(const Data& other)` and standard assignment operator (from `const Data&`) to the class, for unrelated reasons. How can I make sure that when I sort a vector of `Data`, `std::sort` will still use the move-constructor and move-assignment?

Comment: Did you try it? You might be surprised at the results.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212701/stdsort-does-not-always-call-stdswap

Comment: If you do make the class copyable and moveable both, you should declare the move constructor `noexcept` (assuming it is). Doesn't affect `sort` performance, but it will make a difference when adding elements to the `vector` because of its strong exception guarantee.

Comment: @Praetorian If class `T` has a `noexcept` move constructor, will `std::vector<T>` have a `noexcept` move constructor too?

Comment: @quant_dev: Those are not related. Vector's move constructor moves its buffer, not individual T instances (note: the small buffer optimization is not valid for std::vector).

Comment: "How can I make sure": just for a test, you can add `throw` or `abort` to your copy constructor/assignment and check that sorting does not hit it. Or you can declare **but not define** them and check that it still links. Keeping tests for it long term, when you will actually be using copies in other parts of the code, seems painful and unnecessary.

Comment: I ended up not declaring them and adding a `copy` function, to make it clear that normally the `Data` objects are moved, not copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make sure that when I sort a vector of Data, std::sort will
>   still use the move-constructor and move-assignment?

Actually, you don't need to. You have to make sure that the `swap` function used exploits directly or indirectly any trick already used in the move constructor. That is I think how it works. In other words, `sort` needs a good swap, not necessarily a copy.

Where "directly" could mean simply using the default `std::swap` that uses the move constructor when it can.

```
template <class T> void swap (T& a, T& b)
{
  T c(std::move(a)); a=std::move(b); b=std::move(c);
}
```

So, chances are, you don't need to do anything special because `swap` (or as @MarcGlisse noted, the sort algorithm directly) will use the move constructor.

Comment: `sort` is not specified to use only `swap`. If you look at actual implementations, they also use move constructors and move assignments.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, probably right and depends on the implementation I guess. In either case the OP shouldn't worry.

Answer (score 3):

Just provide move-constructor, move-assignment and free `swap`-function (in the same namespace) for your `Data` class