# Why std::sort construct objects?

Tags: c++, sorting, swap, move-constructor, move-assignment-operator

I created the following class to understand **the behavior of `std::sort`**:

```
class X {
public:
  X(int i) : i_(i) { }
  X(X&& rhs) noexcept : i_(std::move(rhs.i_)) { mc_++; }
  X& operator=(X&& rhs) noexcept {
    i_ = std::move(rhs.i_); ao_++; return *this;
  }
  void swap(X& rhs) noexcept { std::swap(i_, rhs.i_); sw_++; } 
  friend bool operator<(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) {
    return lhs.i_ < rhs.i_;
  }
  static void reset() { mc_ = ao_ = sw_ = 0; }
private:
  int i_;
  static size_t mc_, ao_, sw_; // function-call counters
};
// void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs) { lhs.swap(rhs); }
```

And run the following benchmark code:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<X> v;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) v.emplace_back(i);

  std::mt19937 g(0xa41bc9); // fixed seed to compare measurements
  std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);

  X::reset();
  std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

The whole code in online IDE is here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nbwRKptakgCSHK4f.

The measured **number of calls of particular functions** are as follows (all with `-O2` or `/O2` flags):

```
   function:   move ctor    operator=        swap
  GCC 7.1.0:   5,007,335   11,700,048           0
clang 4.0.0:   4,932,061    9,973,899           0
 MSVC 19.11:   8,580,356   21,521,211           0
```

If I uncomment the `swap` function, situation gets better:

```
   function:   move ctor    operator=        swap
  GCC 7.1.0:     999,999    3,685,376   4,007,336
clang 4.0.0:      72,554      254,885   4,859,507
 MSVC 19.11:     906,593    6,173,685   7,673,763
```

However, there still **remains a lot of calls of the move constructor (plus destructor) and the move assignment operator**. What bothers me is the efficiency. For instance, calls of `swap` and `operator=` can be inlined by the compiler, <s>but I guess the compiler may not "inline" (optimize out) the construction/destruction of objects</s>.

**Why is construction/assignment of objects used in sorting?** In-place sorting (which usually `std::sort` does) can be implemented purely by compare and swap operations.

**UPDATE**

My assumption was wrong. It seems perfectly legal to optimize out object creation/destruction, such as in:

```
X temp = std::move(x1);  
x1 = std::move(x2);
x2 = std::move(temp);
```

Therefore, such code can be as efficient as custom `swap`. Online example: https://godbolt.org/g/ud4u9U - there  are no calls of move constructor / assignment operator, though these are not trivial, and their functionality is inlined into `main`.

Comment: Don't think this is a duplicate. There is nothing about _"Why isn't `std::sort` implemented purely by `swap`?"_ in the referred post.

Comment: Were you expecting it to call your `swap` method in the original version? `std::sort` isn't defined to look for `swap` methods.

Comment: @user2357112 No, I were not. I added this measurement just for comparison.

Comment: Potential dupe https://stackoverflow.com/q/14212701/3002139

Comment: "calls of swap and operator= can be inlined by the compiler, but I guess the compiler may not "inline" (optimize out) the construction/destruction of objects" - why would you expect that?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks, this seems to be a reason.

Comment: "For instance, calls of `swap` and `operator=` can be inlined by the compiler, but I guess the compiler may not "inline" (optimize out) the construction/destruction of objects." -- Why wouldn't the compiler be able to inline the constructor and destructor?

Comment: @DanielLangr If you agree it's a dupe tell me, I can hammer.

Comment: Likely wrong assumption. I meant that the object needs to be created (in memory?) while swapping of numbers, pointers, etc. can be done using registers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ok, I agree.

Comment: @user2357112 @hvd Namely, `swap(x1, x2);` needs to touch only 2 memory locations (`x1.i_` and `x2.i_`). Is it true for `X temp = std::move(x1); x1 = std::move(x2); x2 = std::move(temp);` as well? I am not sure wether the object `temp` must be physically created on the stack.

Comment: I don't know the details here, but `std::sort` is probably fairly optimized. I would guess they tried if that helps.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It seems that compilers can completely optimize away object creation/destruction in such cases, see https://godbolt.org/g/ud4u9U.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::sort()` is a hybrid algorithm. While a vanilla quicksort could get away with only `swap()` operations (from `std::partition()`)  the real sorting approach most likely uses insertion, heap, and/or merge sort, too. For these sorting algorithms it is generally more effective to lift an object out of the way (by move construction), moving objects into the current "hole", and finally moving the out of place ibject out of the way. It *may* be reasonable to keep just one temporary object but most likely the algorithm uses some functions and keeping on temporary ibject around is somewhat impractical (although something I hadn't contemplated before and possibly worth trying).

Earlier this year my [Quicker Sorting](https://youtu.be/jz9xIfvAd30) talk got recorded at the [Italian C++ Conference](https://github.com/italiancpp/itcppcon17): it goes over the details of making quicksort quick.

The upshot is: if you want to sort objects you better make sure that copy/move construction, copy/move assignment, destructor, and `swap()` are fast. I can imagine that keeping a temporary object could lessen the need for construction and destruction but assignments will remain. A dedicated *destructive* move could possibly improve performance, too, but I haven't experimented with that (yet).

Comment: Insertion sort and heapsort can be implemented with compare&swap operations only as well (see, e.g., https://github.com/DanielLangr/AQsort/blob/master/include/impl/sequential_sort.h). But I see your point and understand that move can be sometimes more efficient, such as with `_GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3`.