# Sort two vectors with paired data

Tags: c++, sorting, iterator, std, move-semantics

My inputs are pairs of `int`s. They are stored in `std::vector<int>`s `vec1` and `vec2`. (`vec1[i]`, `vec2[i]`) corresponds to a single data-point. I want to sort this data.

### Example:

Input:

- vec1 = [ 6, -3, 18, 0]
- vec2 = [100, 2, 3, 4]

Output:

- vec1 = [-3, 0, 6, 18]
- vec2 = [2, 4, 100, 3]

In the above example, `vec1` was sorted using the order of integers. `vec2` was modified to keep `vec1[i]` and `vec2[i]` aligned.

### An Idea

I would like  [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to handle the sorting algorithm for me. To do this, I would define a new iterator type

```
class IteratorType {
 private:
    int i;
    std::vector<int>& vec1;
    std::vector<int>& vec2;

public:
    
    DereferenceType& operator* ()
    {
        return DereferenceType{i, vec1, vec2}; // error: temporary returned as reference
    }

};
```

When `std::sort` swaps two elements, the iterators are dereferenced and the swap is made. [It does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212701/stdsort-does-not-always-call-stdswap) that this swap is guaranteed to be made with `std::swap` or `std::move`. For my example, I'll create a new `DereferenceType` with an overloaded move operator.

```
class DereferenceType {
 private:
    int i;
    std::vector<int>& vec1;
    std::vector<int>& vec2;

 public:
    DereferenceType& DereferenceType::operator= (DereferenceType&&){
        // overload std::move
    }
};
```

Making `std::move` not behave like a move may violate an assumption of `std::sort`. I also don't like that I have to store `std::vector<int>& vec1;` and `std::vector<int>& vec2;` in each `DereferenceType`.

### The Question

Are there simpler (or more canonical) ways of getting the behavior I want?

Comment: why don't you use `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` ?

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine because the input is from LeetCode. I agree that interview questions often don't give sensible input formats.

Comment: so use the two vectors to merge it into a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` ?

Comment: *To continue, I may need to overload swap and move in namespace std*. Do not that you are not allowed to add overloads into `std`

Comment: @NathanOliver I meant specialize. I believe you are allowed to specialize as of C++20. I'll correct in OP. **Edit:** Nathan is right. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @mbang You are not allowed to specialize functions in `std` since C++20 as well so that will also be a no-go for you.

Comment: Agree with @justANewbstandswithUkraine. I assume (perhaps incorrectly but I am feeling confident on it) anyone with experience in C++ would use `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`. It is going to be hard for you to get an answer on something nobody would attempt...